# Override the Java DefaultStyledDocument implementation

Tags: java, swing

I'm a student. When I learn the GOF , I want to create the word processor mentioned in Chapter2. I choose to use Java swing, I want to extend the DefaultStyledDocument and override the insertUpdate and related methods in order to implement and manage my own Element tree, so I can practice the Composite and Flyweight Pattern. The problem is when I override the insertUpdate method, insert newline has no effect. When inserting a newline, My Element tree will create a new Paragraph(BrachElement), but the cursor don't move to the next line, Swing just don't show it and my following characters just in the same line.

Can anyone help me, thanks.

Comment: Are you calling the super() implementation? Also, it might be safer to add a DocumentListener rather than subclass DefaultStyledDocument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to understand how your structure changes
http://java-sl.com/JEditorPaneStructureTool.html

And this
http://java-sl.com/JEditorPaneTables.html
to see how to change the structures

Comment: I use the JEditorPaneStructureTool, it is so cool. What I found is My Element Tree updated, but the corresponding View Tree didn't. When insert newline, I have a ParagraphElement, but didn't have the corresponding ParagraphView. What should I do to update the View Tree.

Comment: It depends on how you insert the paragraph. You should manually fire correct events. Could you post your code?